# Javascript ensuring object not undefined by OR with empty object

Tags: javascript

I've got a piece of code from a library which has the following. What is the purpose of `options = options || {}` ?

```
var x = function(options) {
        options = options || {}; 
        if ('select_message' in options) 
            options.selectMessage = options.select_message;
        // something else

    }
```

At first glance, it seems that options will become either true or false since it uses a boolean operator. But that doesn't really make sense. My hypothesis is that it ensures that "options" will not be undefined, i.e. something like below.

```
if (typeof options != 'undefined')
    options = {};
```

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: You ask "What is the purpose...?", but the subject line of your question already answers that. The `||` operator doesn't return `true` or `false` if neither of its operands are `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks @Ian. I didn't know about this before, so it was just my hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `options` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (`undefined`, `false`, `null`, `0`, etc) it is assigned `{}` (an anonymous object). It is a common pattern when optional arguments can be provided via an object. By making sure `options` is assigned at the very least an anonymous object, it makes later code not have to check if it is defined or not when accessing properties on options (like `options.something`).

MDN: [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: ".. undefined [or any other false-y value].." - sometimes it must be explicitly checked as per the OPs proposed snippet at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The || is a binary operator that will return the first truthy value.  If you do Boolean({}) => true.  If options is undefined, {} is return and options is set to this value.

You're thinking is correct.  If options passes in something that is "truthy" (http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), object is set to itself, or just remains the same object.  If it is "falsey", it will be set to an empty object.